# Is there other solution instead of iBeacon for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios7, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I know that apple publish the iBeacon based on Bluetooth 4.0 protocol.

In any bluetooth device, if we code device with the following:

```
  0x4c,
  0x00,
  0x02,
  0x15,
```

means that presents this bluetooth device is a iBeacon bluetooth device.

```
static uint8 advertData1[] = 
{ 
  // 25 byte ibeacon advertising data
  // Preamble: 0x4c000215
  // UUID: E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0
  // Major: 1 (0x0001)
  // Minor: 1 (0x0001)
  // Measured Power: -59 (0xc5)
  0x1A, // length of this data including the data type byte
  GAP_ADTYPE_MANUFACTURER_SPECIFIC, // manufacturer specific advertisement data type
  0x4c,
  0x00,
  0x02,
  0x15,
  0xe2,
  0xc5,
  0x6d,
  0xb5,
  0xdf,
  0xfb,
  0x48,
  0xd2,
  0xb0,
  0x60,
  0xd0,
  0xf5,
  0xa7,
  0x10,
  0x96,
  0xe0,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x07,
  0xc5
};
```

my question is if i define my own protocol, that means i change this

```
  0x4c,
  0x00,
  0x02,
  0x15,
```

is there a possibility that i can identify my own defined bluetooth device via iphone without addtional identifying device on the iphone.

does apple support customrized ibeacon?

***EDIT***
according to what davidgyoung said, i did some research on stackoverflow to share with others with ibeacon quesitons

1. [iOS CoreBluetooth / iBeacon: Advertise an iBeacon and a peripheral service concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351856/ios-corebluetooth-ibeacon-advertise-an-ibeacon-and-a-peripheral-service-concu)
   comments are very helpful
2. [Using CoreBluetooth with iBeacons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387327/using-corebluetooth-with-ibeacons)
3. [iOS 7 Tutorial Series: Core Location Beacons](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/christopher-mann/ios-7-tutorial-series-core-location-beacons)
4. [Using CoreBluetooth with iBeacons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387327/using-corebluetooth-with-ibeacons)
5. [iBeacon Monitoring in the Background and Foreground](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly define your own custom Bluetooth LE advertisement on iOS and use it as a beacon.

But you will not be able to use CoreLocation APIs to detect these nonstandard iBeacons.  You must use CoreBluetooth APIs, and this will impose restrictions on permissions and background usage.

Comment: thnx, @davidgyoung;  r u to say: 1.if using CoreLocation, it can get to background detecting the ibeacon devices, if yes, could u tell me how? ;  2. could u be more specific on CoreBluetooth APIs  restrictions on permissions

Comment: Here is a detailed explanation of background iBeacon behavior: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html. as far as permissions go, if you use CoreLocation, iOS will ask to use your current location of the user.  If you use CoreBluetooth, it will not.